# Drupal How to import content (form and confirmationpage) with exclusive styling, with the ability to place on any page

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I come from Wordpress and need to re-build in Drupal.

Looking for a way to place a form with customised confirmation and it's own css file and images within one or more Drupal site. What is the best way to make such a setup.

What I would like is to have the freedom to place it at a random page without to much dependencies.

Its a package of five forms each with personalised feedback css and images.

Answer (score 0):

You can create webform from code by usin Drupal's webform API. But much easier solution is to install webform module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

Every form has unique id so you can use it to "aim" it with CSS and style just that form - check on page source.

And webform can also put forms into blocks so you put them on any page at any region.